# How do I create the first line in a new Google Spreadsheet using the API?

Tags: java, gwt, google-sheets, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

This is how I create the spreadsheet:

```
DocsService client= new DocsService ("idea");
client.useSsl ();
client.setOAuthCredentials (oauthParameters, new OAuthHmacSha1Signer ());

DocumentListEntry newEntry= new com.google.gdata.data.docs.SpreadsheetEntry ();
newEntry.setTitle (new PlainTextConstruct ("GIdeaDB"));
DocumentListEntry insertedEntry= client.insert (new URL (
  "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/?xoauth_requestor_id="+ userEmail), newEntry);
```

Now I want to write the first line in it.

But unfortunately all API calls seam to base on the fact, that there already is a first line, for you insert name-value-pairs (where the name is the headline I want to create).
http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#CreatingTableRecords

Any ideas how I can create the first line? The one which defines the field names.

Comment: This changes the size of the worksheet. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#modifying_a_worksheets_title_and_size

Comment: Offical docs are here - Updating [or creating] multiple cells with a batch request: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#updating_multiple_cells_with_a_batch_request

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finaly found it. You have to do it cell by cell:

```
  oauthParameters= new GoogleOAuthParameters ();
  oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey (CONSUMER_KEY);
  oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret (CONSUMER_SECRET);
  oauthParameters.setOAuthType (OAuthType.TWO_LEGGED_OAUTH);
  oauthParameters.setScope ("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/");

  SpreadsheetService spreadsheetService= new SpreadsheetService ("appname");
  spreadsheetService.useSsl ();
  spreadsheetService.setOAuthCredentials (oauthParameters,
    new OAuthHmacSha1Signer ());

  URL feedUrl= new URL (
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com"
      + "/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full?title=Spreadsheetname&xoauth_requestor_id="
      + userEmail);

  SpreadsheetFeed resultFeed= spreadsheetService.getFeed (feedUrl,
    SpreadsheetFeed.class);

  List <SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets= resultFeed.getEntries ();
  SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheetEntry= spreadsheets.get (0);

  URL worksheetFeedUrl= spreadsheetEntry.getWorksheetFeedUrl ();
  log.severe (worksheetFeedUrl.toString ());
  WorksheetFeed worksheetFeed= spreadsheetService.getFeed (
    worksheetFeedUrl, WorksheetFeed.class);

  List <WorksheetEntry> worksheetEntrys= worksheetFeed.getEntries ();
  WorksheetEntry worksheetEntry= worksheetEntrys.get (0);

  // Write header line into Spreadsheet
  URL cellFeedUrl= worksheetEntry.getCellFeedUrl ();
  CellFeed cellFeed= spreadsheetService.getFeed (cellFeedUrl,
    CellFeed.class);

  CellEntry cellEntry= new CellEntry (1, 1, "headline1");
  cellFeed.insert (cellEntry);
  cellEntry= new CellEntry (1, 2, "headline2");
  cellFeed.insert (cellEntry);
```

Comment: i want to show header as MOnth-Year but when i put value as August-2014 it turns it into date like 1/8/2014. any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but it looks to me like that is described in the section on "Creating a table":

```
TableEntry tableEntry = new TableEntry();

FeedURLFactory factory = FeedURLFactory.getDefault();
URL tableFeedUrl = factory.getTableFeedUrl(spreadsheetEntry.getKey());

// Specify a basic table:
tableEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("New Table"));
tableEntry.setWorksheet(new Worksheet("Sheet1"));
tableEntry.setHeader(new Header(1));

// Specify columns in the table, start row, number of rows.
Data tableData = new Data();
tableData.setNumberOfRows(0);
// Start row index cannot overlap with header row.
tableData.setStartIndex(2);
// This table has only one column.
tableData.addColumn(new Column("A", "Column A"));

tableEntry.setData(tableData);
service.insert(tableFeedUrl, tableEntry);
```

Specifically, the part `tableEntry.setHeader(new Header(1))` seems like it creates a header on the first row. Then, `tableData.setStartIndex(2)` seems to specify that data shouldn't go in the first row (since it's the header). Finally, `tableData.addColumn(new Column("A", "Column A"))` seems to add a column that would be labeled in the header.

Comment: Hey, that looks prommissing! Gonna try it on monday. Thx!

Comment: Hmm.. no :-( It says "Spreadsheets creates a new table. The table is not visible in the GUI, but you can operate on it using the Data API." I would also want to see the Spreadsheet in Google Docs, so this is not the option

Comment: Wouldn't the "GUI" it's referring being the app GUI? Since the GData API operates only on server-synced data. It just means it will not _show_ a table to the user, just create it in memory.